# Why do we pass function arguments as void* in pthread_create?

Tags: c++, multithreading, operating-system

I have just started an Operating System course and currently we are learning multi-threading, so I am new to all this.

Here is my question: Whenever we create a thread using pthread_create(), why do we need to pass the arguments of the function we want our thread to run in type void*?

For example, consider the following code.

```
void *test(void* data)
{
   ...
}

int main()
{
      int temp;
      pthread_t tid;
      pthread_attr_t attr;
   
      pthread_attr_init(&attr);
      pthread_create(&tid, &attr, test, (void*)&temp);
}
```

So, here in,

```
pthread_create(&tid, &attr, test, (void*)&temp);
```

why do we need to type cast the integer to void*. Why not just pass integer as is? And similarly, instead of

```
void* test(void* data);
```

why not this,

```
void* test(int data);
```

Comment: Think of how `pthread_create` could be declared. How would you declare it for all types in a way which would also work in C?

Comment: what if you want to pass in two `int`s, or any other combination of whatever?

Comment: pthreads are a C api. There is no overloading, no templates, etc. There has to be one fixed interface, that can allow for all kinds of functions to be called. When you use a C++ thread, you [really do pass the arguments as their real types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First off, `pthread_create()` is a **C** function, not C++, so all the things C++ *could* do at this point -- e.g. something using templates -- is not possible. C programs want to start threads as well.

(Actually newer versions of C++ have their own [threading interface](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread).)

So, C.

The idea is to have a *generic* interface, so you can pass *anything* to *any* function to be called by `pthread_create()`, and *return* anything as well.

You can't pass-by-value, because you don't know the *size* of the argument. Is it `int`, `double`, or `struct something`? So you need to pass by pointer.

And since you don't know the *type* of the argument (and return value) either, you use `void *`, the "anonymous" pointer type. Inside the called thread function (`test()` in this case), you *do* know the type of the argument and return value, so you can cast from and to `void *` as appropriate.

Comment: @MuzahirHussain: It's a basic concept of C, really. Whenever you see `void *`, it means "generic *something*". Ref. [memcpy()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy), [qsort()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort), [bsearch()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/bsearch). Once you realize that, `void *` will never confuse you again. Just, **don't** use `void *` in C++, it's basically *always* a design flaw.

Comment: This sounds reasonable. However, `printf()` shows that in C you can actually pass a variable number of arguments to a function without restricting size, type or number. So, why not `pthread_create(pthread_t*, pthrad_attr_t*, ...)` ? I believe the actual reason is that POSIX is intentionally simple.

Comment: @MSalters: Varargs are solving a different problem, that of a variable-length argument list. We *know* the exact number of arguments here, we just don't know their exact type. Besides, you would *still* need to pull them off the stack as `void *`, because there is nothing to tell you what *type* actually "hides" behind it (no `printf()`-style format string). You would have won nothing, and added a possible error cause (too few / wrong type of arguments)

Comment: @DevSolar: Why would I need to pull them from the stack as `void*`? `pthread_create` needs to create a stack for me anyway. It could just copy the whole vararg list to that new stack, so my thread entry function can retrieve them using the normal vararg mechanism. Remember that in `pthread_create` the caller controls both sides. I know what I pass.

Comment: @MSalters: Ah... think-o. Mentally dropped the "caller controls both sides" ball there for a minute. Yes, perhaps varargs might have been a solution as well -- but only for the arguments, not the return value.

Comment: In general, the underlying OS controls both sides.  Its threading API calls must support ALL languages and copying a variable block of data to the stack of a new thread is not supported on any OS API I've used.

Comment: @MartinJames: "Supporting all languages" usually amounts to "supporting C", because that is what (virtually) all languages interface, but I see where you're coming from.

Comment: @DevSolar sue, C is the lowest common denominator of code and void* is the LCD of data.